# Get element by id show error in c# selenium

Tags: c#, .net, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

Full my source code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System.Threading;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Set up ChromeDriver
        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("--disable-notifications");
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        // Configure the browser to mimic real human behavior
        driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.amazon.com/");

        // Randomize actions to simulate human-like behavior
        var random = new Random();

        // Read product names from a file
        List<string> productNames = ReadProductNamesFromFile("productNames.txt");

        // Perform searches and view product details
        foreach (string productName in productNames)
        {
            // Clear cookies and reset browser state
            ClearBrowserState(driver);

            // Search for a product
            SearchProduct(driver, productName);

            // Get the list of product links
            IReadOnlyList<IWebElement> productLinks = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a.a-link-normal.s-no-outline"));

            if (productLinks.Count > 0)
            {
                // Pick a product based on highest rating
                IWebElement selectedProduct = GetProductWithHighestRating(productLinks);

                if (selectedProduct != null)
                {
                    // Move the mouse to the product link before clicking
                    MoveToElement(driver, selectedProduct);
                    Thread.Sleep(random.Next(1000, 3000));

                    // Click on the product link
                    ClickElement(selectedProduct);
                    Thread.Sleep(random.Next(2000, 5000));

                    // Simulate scrolling and viewing product details
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    {
                        // Scroll down by a random offset
                        ScrollBy(driver, random.Next(150, 400));
                        Thread.Sleep(random.Next(1000, 3000));

                        // Scroll to a random element on the page
                        ScrollToElement(driver, selectedProduct);
                        Thread.Sleep(random.Next(1000, 3000));
                    }

                    // Randomly view product images
                    if (random.Next(0, 2) == 0)
                    {
                        // Get the list of product image links
                        IReadOnlyList<IWebElement> imageLinks = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("img.s-image"));

                        if (imageLinks.Count > 0)
                        {
                            // Randomly select a product image link to click
                            int randomIndex = random.Next(imageLinks.Count);
                            IWebElement imageLink = imageLinks[randomIndex];

                            // Click on the product image link
                            ClickElement(imageLink);
                            Thread.Sleep(random.Next(2000, 5000));

                            // Go back to the product details page
                            NavigateBack(driver);
                            Thread.Sleep(random.Next(2000, 5000));
                        }
                    }

                    // Go back to the search results page
                    NavigateBack(driver);
                    Thread.Sleep(random.Next(5000, 10000));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"No suitable product found for: {productName}");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"No product links found for: {productName}");
            }
        }

        // Close the browser
        driver.Quit();
    }

    static void ClearBrowserState(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("about:blank");
    }

    static void SearchProduct(IWebDriver driver, string productName)
    {
         IWebElement searchBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("twotabsearchtextbox"));

        searchBox.Clear();
        searchBox.SendKeys(productName);
        searchBox.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
    }

    static void MoveToElement(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element)
    {
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.MoveToElement(element).Perform();
    }

    static void ClickElement(IWebElement element)
    {
        element.Click();
    }

    static void ScrollBy(IWebDriver driver, int yOffset)
    {
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        js.ExecuteScript($"window.scrollBy(0, {yOffset})");
    }

    static void ScrollToElement(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element)
    {
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
    }

    static void NavigateBack(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        driver.Navigate().Back();
    }

    static List<string> ReadProductNamesFromFile(string filePath)
    {
        List<string> productNames = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            // Read the file and add each line as a product name
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
            productNames.AddRange(lines);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error reading product names from file: {ex.Message}");
        }

        return productNames;
    }

    static IWebElement GetProductWithHighestRating(IReadOnlyList<IWebElement> productLinks)
    {
        double maxRating = 0;
        IWebElement selectedProduct = null;

        foreach (var productLink in productLinks)
        {
            string ratingText = productLink.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".a-icon-alt")).Text;
            double rating = ParseRating(ratingText);

            if (rating > maxRating)
            {
                maxRating = rating;
                selectedProduct = productLink;
            }
        }

        return selectedProduct;
    }

    static double ParseRating(string ratingText)
    {
        // Extract the rating value from the text
        string[] parts = ratingText.Split(' ');
        double rating = 0;

        if (parts.Length > 0 && double.TryParse(parts[0], out rating))
        {
            return rating;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

i am trying make auto selenium search product in amazon but it show error when i trying call search product textbox
How to fix it

This code line show error

```
static void SearchProduct(IWebDriver driver, string productName)
{
     IWebElement searchBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("twotabsearchtextbox"));

    searchBox.Clear();
    searchBox.SendKeys(productName);
    searchBox.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
}
```

OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#twotabsearchtextbox"}